# BeautifulSoup-scrape html code from a website not working

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

let me briefly describe the problem. When I use urllib3 to scrape the html from a website, it isn't the same as the html code that I get when I manually enter the website with chrome and use 'inspect element'

Here is an example from my code. The problem is that the html code I got here is different from the html code I would get when I use inspect element on chrome

```
#myUrl is the url of the website I'm trying to scrape

http = urllib3.PoolManager()
response = http.request('GET', myUrl)
soup = BeautifulSoup(response.data.decode('utf-8'), features="html.parser")

m = str(soup)
```

Comment: Is the page loaded dynamically? Please share the URL

Comment: We cannot help you unless you provide the URL

Answer (score 0):

that problem, probably is due to: the content on the page is being loaded with javascript. To get the whole data, you have to use some library that runs javascript. I recommend using Selenium.

To verify that case, you can disable the browser's javascript and trying to load the page.

Comment: Oh thanks, I downloaded the Selenium module to scrape html code from the website and now it's identical to what I get when I use inspect element on google chrome.

Comment: However, there is a problem with selenium. Since selenium opens up a physical browser, some of the website(s) I scrape do not give me access because they've somehow detected that I use "Bots and automation software". It opened a page "perimeterX bot detection"

What's weird is that when I use urllib to scrape data from websites, the websites don't detect any bots and they let me get the data, how can I not get detected as a bot with selenium?

Comment: One of the techniques to pretend to be a human is to put random time waits between actions. When the action is caused by a robot, it is so quick that no one (human) is capable to do it. But in some cases, there are several verifications trying to identify bots, and it makes it hard to accomplish the goals. unfortunately :/